# Conditional probability in a dice game

Tags: probability

Presented with this question:

> Consider a game in which you roll two
>   dice, and you win if the total is $7$ or $11$ and you lose if the total is $2, 3$, or $12$. You keep rolling until one of these
>   totals occurs. Using conditional probability, find the
>   probability that you win.

So my working would be:
Let $A$ be, get $7$ or $11$ in two rolls. Let $B$ be, get $2,3$, or $12$ in two rolls.

Ways to get  $A$ is $8$ and for $B$ is $4$. Total sample size is $36$.
\begin{align*}
P(\text{win})&= P(A |A \text{ or } B)\\
&= \frac{P(A\,\cdot \,A \text{ or }B)}{P(A \text{ or } B)}\\ 
&=\frac{8/12 \cdot 12/36}{12/36}\\
&=\frac{8/36}{12/36}\\
&=\frac{8}{12} \\
&= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}
The final ans is indeed $0.67$.

However is this the right approach to solving the question using conditional probability? I'm told that this is not the right way.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and work in progress in every post. That way you can get answers that are specifically tailored to your needs. Also, please try to learn to type your posts properly. It makes it easier to read. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! i had no idea that there are ways to format the math equations until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

*First approach:*

Let $w=Pr(\text{win in first turn}), l=Pr(\text{lose in first turn}), d = Pr(\text{draw in first turn})$.

Recognize then that $Pr(\text{win overall}) = Pr(\text{win in first turn})+Pr(\text{win in second turn and draw in first turn})$

$~~~~~~~~ + Pr(\text{win in third turn and draw in first two turns}) + \dots$

We have then $Pr(\text{win overall}) = w + dw + d^2w+ d^3w + \dots = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty w\cdot d^k=w\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty d^k$

It remains to calculate what $w,l$ and $d$ are and to compute the infinite sum.  Use what you know about dice and geometric sums to complete.

> $w=\frac{8}{36}=\frac{2}{9}, l=\frac{4}{36}=\frac{1}{9}, d=1-w-l=\frac{6}{9}=\frac{2}{3}$

$~$

> We have then $w\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty d^k = \frac{2}{9}\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{2}{3})^k = \frac{2}{9}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}\right) = \frac{2}{9}\cdot 3 = \frac{2}{3}$

---

*Second approach:*

Recognize that the probability of winning overall depends **only** on the result of the first (and only) time that one of the totals $2,3,7,11,12$ are rolled.  I.e. all trials that you neither won nor lost are completely irrelevant and can be ignored.

We can then calculate:  $Pr(\text{won overall}) = Pr(\text{won}\mid \text{won or lost})$

Using the same notation as above, we see that $Pr(\text{won}\mid\text{won or lost}) = \frac{Pr(\text{won} \cap (\text{won or lost}))}{Pr(\text{won or lost})} = \frac{w}{w+l}$

Again, I will leave calculating $w$ and $l$ and finishing the computations to you.

> As above, $w=\frac{2}{9}$ and $l = \frac{1}{9}$.  So, $\frac{w}{w+l}=\frac{\frac{2}{9}}{\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{9}} = \frac{2}{2+1}=\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

The game ends when you roll one of 7, 11, 2, 3, or 12.  Given that the game ends on a given roll, the (conditional) probability that you have won is $$\frac{P(7) + P(11)}{P(7)+P(11)+P(2)+P(3)+P(12)}.$$  I.e. the probability you win is the probability of getting a winning roll over the probability of getting any roll that ends the game.  To evaluate the probability of a given roll yielding a particular combined sum, see the diagram below.

[image: Probabilities of various dice rolls]

This gives the probability of winning as $\frac{6+2}{6+2+1+2+1} = \frac{8}{12} = \frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong because 
$$P(A|A\cup B) = \frac{P(A\cap(A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)} = \frac{P((A\cap A)\cup (A\cap B))}{P(A\cup B)}=\frac{P(A)}{P(A\cup B)}$$

since $A\cap B=\varnothing$ ($A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive). 
It is ***not***
$$P(A|A\cup B) = \frac{P(A\cdot(A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}=\frac{P(A)P(A\cup B)}{P(A\cup B)} = P(A).$$

It follows (coincidentally) that
$$\frac{P(A)}{P(A\cup B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)} = \frac{8/36}{8/36+4/36+0} = \frac{8}{12} = \frac{2}{3}$$

In other words, I believe you got it right for the wrong reason.